# Significance Test for Comparing RMSE values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, model-comparison

I want to use the RMSE measurement to compare 3 statistical regression models against a baseline model.
I want to do this based on a null hypothesis testing framework where I train the models using n-fold cross-validation and perform a significance test.

My question is, which significance test should I use in the RMSE case?

Comment: What is your null hypothesis?

Comment: @Dave That there is no statistical significance between the RMSE of the baseline model and each of the other models RMSE values

Comment: So something like ANOVA but first RMSEs instead of means? (As a heads up, “statistically significant” is never part of a null hypothesis.)

Comment: @Dave I was thinking that I would need to use a Wilcoxon sign test?

Comment: With one observation per model?

Comment: @Dave If I use n-crossvalidation I would have n observations per model?

Comment: Then you have a violation of independence.

Comment: @David Do you perhaps have another suggestion? :)

Comment: I've had similar thoughts but never did pursue the PRESS statistic that whuber mentioned: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/452453/regression-hypothesis-testing-via-out-of-sample-testing