# comparing glmnet models

Tags: r, glmnet

The `anova` function doesn't allow comparison of glmnet models:

```
data(QuickStartExample)
x <- QuickStartExample$x; y <- QuickStartExample$y
set.seed(11)
fit1 = glmnet(x[,1:10], y, lambda=0.1)
fit2 = glmnet(x[,11:20], y, lambda=0.1)

anova(fit1, fit2)

Error in UseMethod("anova") : 
  no applicable method for 'anova' applied to an object of class "c('elnet', 'glmnet')"
```

Is there an alternative?

EDIT:
Based on Roland's comment, I should perform cross-validation

For predictors `x[,1:10]`:

```
cv.train.fit1 <- cv.glmnet(x[1:70,1:10], y[1:70])
best.lambda <- cv.train.fit1$lambda.min
fit1 <- glmnet(x[71:100,1:10], y[71:100] ,lambda=best.lambda)
```

For predictors `x[,11:20]`:

```
cv.train.fit2 <- cv.glmnet(x[1:70,11:20], y[1:70])
best.lambda <- cv.train.fit2$lambda.min
fit2 <- glmnet(x[71:100,11:20], y[71:100], lambda=best.lambda)
```

But the question remains, how can I compare the performance of `fit1` and `fit2`?

Comment: What do you want to compare, how the first ten features predict compared to the next ten features?

Comment: I'm not sure what the goal is here. ANOVA compares nested models and your models are not nested. Also, if you have a reason to test two sets of predictors, you should compare LASSO regression predictive performance, e.g., based on cross-validation.

Comment: @Dave, yes, the idea would be to test if the predictors in f1 explain y better than the predictors in f2

Comment: @Roland, yes, that's the idea, testing two sets of predictors against each other. Do you mean running `cv.glmnet(x,y)` for f1 predictors and f2 predictors separately?

Comment: Well, the function returns the mean cross-validated error for each lambda. But you probably should also test/compare performance with data that wasn't used for tuning lambda. Basically, apply machine learning principles because your problem seems to be a machine learning problem.

Comment: Thanks @Roland, but I'm a bit confused. Should I run `cv.glmnet` on training data and then test it on test data for both set of predictors? But then how do I compare which set has more predictive power? I edited my question with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I believe could be useful:

```
set.seed(42)
f <- 1:70

#tune model on training fold
cv.train.fit1 <- cv.glmnet(x[f,1:10], y[f])
best.lambda <- cv.train.fit1$lambda.min
fit1 <- glmnet(x[f,1:10], y[f] ,lambda=best.lambda)

cv.train.fit2 <- cv.glmnet(x[f,11:20], y[f])
best.lambda <- cv.train.fit2$lambda.min
fit2 <- glmnet(x[f,11:20], y[f], lambda=best.lambda)

#assess performance on testing fold   
sqrt(mean((y[-f] - predict(fit1, newx = x[-f,1:10]))^2))
#[1] 2.188628
sqrt(mean((y[-f] - predict(fit2, newx = x[-f,11:20]))^2))
#[1] 2.549974
```

Clearly, `fit1` performs better for this fold. You could turn this into cross-validation by creating a loop that subsets the data into training and testing folds. You should have additional hold-out data to assess final performance of the selected model.

Comment: [Related?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/452453/247274)

Comment: Thanks Roland, that was helpful. If I create loop that subsets the training data can the first iteration be samples `[1,4,10,33,63]` and the second iteration samples `[1,4,18,29,63]`? or do the samples always need to be different in each loop, for example, `sample1=[1,4,10,22,63]`, `sample2=[3,5,36,59,70]`, `sample3=[2,6,8,11,23]`,etc?

Comment: So your suggestion is to create a vector with the mean error from each iteration, right? So let's say `fit1.errors=[2.18,1.42,1.23,1.12]` and `fit2.errors=[2.36,3.34,1.55,3.74]`. I can see the average `fit1.errors` is smaller, but how can I assess whether it's meaningfully smaller? Should I simply run a t.test or something between `fit1.errors` and `fit2.errors`?

Comment: I decided to ask a [separate question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/633364/comparing-glmnet-models-part-2) as there are at least three points I'm still unclear about.

Comment: @locus You don't seem to know how cross-validation works. The Wikipedia article might get you started ...

Comment: According to Wikipedia, both are valid. Partitioning the samples without overlap in the different folds would be `K-fold cross-validation`, with overlap would be `Monte Carlo cross-validation`